# Battery died at a drive-in and the guy that jumped off the car with a jump box hooked a jump box up backward

Tags: battery, toyota, camry, acceleration

After you hit the jump box up backwards I attempted to start the car twice before I realized that he hooked it up backwards it is a 2011 Toyota Camry now the car starts but it has no acceleration at all and it has a check engine light on but I have no way to get it to get the light checked

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, something was damaged during the jumper box mishap. The big things being the alternator or the engine control unit (ECU). Since you can still start it, I'd suspect these are probably still in working order. The battery was recharged after the "successful" jump, which means the alternator is working. And since it will run, the ECU is at least attempting to work.

There's not a whole lot you can do until you can figure out what the codes are behind the check engine light. One thing you can do is to check fuses. There's probably two sets of fuses. I'd just go through and methodically check each one. If you don't have a digital multimeter to check them in their slots, you'll need to carefully pull each one and see if they are blown, replacing any which gave up the ghost.